# How can I remove the default user folders?

Tags: windows-10

How can I remove the default user folders in Windows 10?

[image: Default Windows 10 Administrators folder]

[image: Default Windows 10 Public folder]

I did try:

- DisableKnownFolders - Failed
- Modifying registry (User Shell Folders/User Folders) - Failed

What else is there to remove them?

Comment: have u tried this methods?https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6015-add-remove-folders-pc-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? Do you have a (really good) reason to?

Comment: @Seth They are not necessary on a locked down system.